# How are new werewolves made?

Tags: werewolf, twilight

How are new werewolves made in the Twilight series?

I mean, if werewolves don't harm humans then how did they get new ones? Are they born like humans?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wolves of the Quileute tribe (seen in Twilight) have inherited the ability from [Taha Aki](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Taha_Aki). His story was told in *Eclipse*.

They are not strictly werewolves, but shape-shifters. This is a misconception the Volturi also make.

Actual [Children of the Moon](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Moon) spread their lycanthropy through bite.

Answer (score 2):

Quileute men (usually) who posses the dormant "Werewolf" gene, which is hereditary and seemingly dominant, and who come into contact with a vampire, "awaken" as shapeshifters. They therefore reproduce in the usual way: sexually. However, not every male with the gene awakens -- there's an age restriction as well, preventing the fathers of the main werewolf cast from awakening despite carrying the gene.